# How to use fadeTo to fade out instead of in? jQuery.fadeTo in reverse

Tags: jquery, html, opacity

I'd like to use jQuery.fadeTo to change the opacity from 1 to say .7

```
jQuery("#my-element").fadeTo(2000, .7);
```

The result of this code starts my element at opacity 0 and *fades in* to .7 after 2 seconds.

I'd like to have my element start at opacity 1 and *fade out* to .7

Comment: `.fadeTo()` fades an element from its current opacity, not zero, to whatever you specify.

Comment: Vote to close. I'm not even sure what the problem was at this point but it was on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) takes duration as the first argument and opacity as the second. Swap these please. And make sure that before you start the fadeTo call, the opacity is 1:

```
jQuery("#my-element").css({opacity: 1});
jQuery("#my-element").fadeTo(2000, 0.7);
```

[UPDATE: Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kXwJB/)

Comment: Demo is working for me. There seems to be some other problem in my actual code. I have a feeling that the CSS opacity is not getting set to 1 initially maybe due to the fact that I'm adding my element to the page dynamically.

Comment: IE8 and earlier use `filter:alpha(opacity=x)`. The `x` can take a value from 0 - 100. A lower value makes the element more transparent.